# Thebes: extending your turn past the end of the last year

Tags: thebes

In the game Thebes, does my last turn have to end exactly on the last week of 1903, or can I extend it into 1904?

If it can be extended, is there a limit on how far into 1904 I may go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the reference document at OrderOfGamers.com](http://www.orderofgamers.com/games/thebes/),

> Once players are in 1903, when a player’s marker crosses space 52 he must end on space 1. He may use no more weeks. Once all players have reached 
>   the space, the game ends and scoring commences.

You must stop on week 1 of (what would be) the year 1904, and you may not use any weeks beyond that.